# Concourse - fly CLI - Limit to specific job name

Tags: concourse

Is it possible in Concourse to limit to a task inside the pipeline? Let's say I have a pipeline with three jobs, but I want test just job #2 not 1 and 3. I tried to do a trigger job by pointing to a pipeline/job-name and it kind of worked (i.e., `fly -t lab tj -j bbr-backup-bosh/export-om-installation`). 'Kind of' because it did start from this job and then it fired off other jobs that I didn't want to test anyway. Wondering if there Ansible-like (i.e., `--tag`)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "limit" a triggered job to itself, since a job is part of a pipeline. Each time you trigger a job, it will keep `put`ting all the resources it uses. These resources, if marked as `trigger: true` downstream, well, they will trigger the downstream jobs.

You have two possibilities:

1. do not mark any resource in the pipeline as `trigger: true`. This obviously also means that your pipeline will never advance automatically, you will need to manual trigger each job. Not ideal but maybe good enough while troubleshooting the pipeline itself.
2. Think in terms of tasks. A job is made of one or more tasks, and tasks can be run independently from the pipeline. See the documentation for `fly execute` and for example https://concoursetutorial.com/ where they explain tasks and `fly execute`. Note that `fly execute` supports also `--input` and `--output`, so it is possible to emulate the task inputs and outputs as if it were in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Marco is pretty dead on but there’s one other option. You could pause the other jobs and abort any builds that would be triggered after they’re unpaused